# Mockito: How to mock field dependencies partially in spring bean

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I have a Spring service with multiple field dependencies as below. One of the dependency (`thirdPartyService`) communicates with an external application. How can I just mock that?

```
@Service
public class PlannerServiceImpl implements PlannerService {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PlannerServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryA repositoryA;

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryB repositoryB;

    @Autowired
    private ThirdPartyService thirdPartyService ;

}
```

If I use Mock annotation then it still connects to external application instead of returning mock response:

```
@Mock
ThirdPartyService thirdPartyService;

@Autowired
PlannerService plannerService;
```

And If I use `InjectMocks` annotation then it gives `NullpointerException` for `RepositoryA` and `RepositoryB`.

```
@Mock
ThirdPartyService thirdPartyService;

@InjectMocks 
PlannerService plannerService = newPlannerService();
```

How can I just Mock `ThirdPartyService` and let Spring inject other dependencies?

Comment: Just create a configuration for test which instead of the actual bean has a mock of the service. That way you will always have a mock for that service.

Comment: I am having similar problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: See answer from Alexander K

Answer (score 1):

You can modify what Spring has injected using `Whitebox`. Optionally, since you are using Spring, you can also use `ReflectionTestUtils.setField`

After Spring injects the dependencies, and before your unit test runs, you can use `org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox` to modify Spring's injection. Something like this

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(plannerService, "thirdPartyService" thirdPartyService);
```

Where `thirdPartyService` is your mocked instance.

[javadoc here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-reflect/1.6.4/org/powermock/reflect/Whitebox.html#setInternalState-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

or using Spring's `ReflectionTestUtils`:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField((plannerService, "thirdPartyService" thirdPartyService);
```

[java doc here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

This can typically be done in your "setup" method, the one annotated with `@Before`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a setter method in your `PlannerService` class under test

```
void  setRepositoryA(RepositoryA repository) {
    this.repositoryA = repository;
}
```

And then use this method in your test to supply a mock implementation of the `RepositoryA`

Or you can @Inject the repository in the constructor and then in your unit test call the constructor with the mocks as the arguments, instead.

Answer (score -2):

The `@Autowiring` and `@InejctMocks` can be used in a test case for sure (annotations being used separately on different instance fields).

Make sure you:

**1)** Initiate Mockito mocks in the `@Before` method:

```
@Before
public void before(){
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

**2)** Use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class` in the `@RunWith` class annotation